# import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity " The type ActionBarActivity is deprecated"

Tags: java, android, eclipse

How to resolve error import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity " The type ActionBarActivity is deprecated" in eclipse

Answer (score 4):

ActionBarActivity is deprecated. You have to replace it with AppCompatActivity in v7 support library.

Comment: how can you please guide me i am new i can post picture here need 10 reputation

Comment: Replace ActionBarActivity with AppCompatActivity. Use "Theme.AppCompat" themes. Stop using Eclipse and use Android Studio.